# Maintain a list of active Linux lab machines

Tags: linux

I've always got a few machines kicking around that are waiting for their next real job (often machines are at the end of their production life, still powered on, and are waiting for the bin!). I'd like to use these machines as a testing lab and in order to do that, I need to maintain a list of active machines that can be used, with their current status and ideally, a way to connect to that machine.

Machines are in different networks, behind different firewalls sometimes, so a system that maintains a list of active machines, and an agent or reverse ssh connection would be fantastic, so I can easily connect to that lab machine and run some sort of test on it.

So far, I've only found beaker (http://beaker-project.org) which is RHEL/Fedora only (not that much of a problem), but it's very specific to software testing and I don't do that very often. Otherwise, it looks okay.

Summary; I want a list of IP addresses of Linux machines from different networks that are powered on and active, and a way to connect to that machine. If a machine is powered off or reinstalled, it's removed from the list.

Thanks!